# Event on PDF Iframe is loaded - Javascript

Tags: jquery, pdf, iframe, loaded

Is there any easiest method to call a function right after a `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>` is loaded? i just want to show a `preloader.gif` on content load. `ready()` or `onload()` didn't help. any suggestion?

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $file; ?>" id="read" width="100%" height="440" border="0"></iframe>

$('#read').ready(function () {
    $('#preloader').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using any javascript. Just wrap your `iframe` in some `div` like

```
<div class="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe src="<?php echo $file; ?>" id="read" width="100%" height="440" border="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

And use a CSS class to set the loading background

```
.iframe-wrapper {
  background:url(../images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: this shows loader.gif and vanishes as instant as PDF file starts loading in iframe but not on loading completion.